# How to get custom price by observer in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, price, quote

How to get custom price by observer in magento?

My code:

```
public function updatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
{ 
    $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();

    //$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData();

    foreach ($quote['data_object']->getAllItems() as $key => $item) {
        if( !$item->getCustomPrice() ){
            echo "Hello";
            print_r($customPrice); die;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add your custom price attribute to quote object.

Add this to you `config.xml`:

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <custom_price />
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

Observer:

```
public function updatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        if (!$product->getCustomPrice()) {
            echo "Hello";
            ...
        }
    }
}
```